# How much RAM saved / latency added from new KV Table

Tags: eosjs, eosio.cdt

How much RAM do the KV Tables save / how much additional latency does this storage type add to the trx lifecycle?

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is far too generic to generate a clear answer. The answer will likely depend on what your chain data looks like.